# Insert into Hive ORC table by nested POJO

Tags: java, hadoop, jdbc, hive

We have a hive server to store the big data we want to use.
It has a table stored as ORC format.
I'm new for this field, and I would like to know that,
is there a way/lib to simply insert into the hive table by POJO?

like :

```
hiveLib.insert(new Item(...));
public class Item {
    private String orderItemId;
    private String itemId;
    private MultiLang name;
    private MultiLang url;
    private MultiLang imgUrl;
}
```

And it's nested.
Thanks.

Comment: Hive supports Struct types, which are nested objects. Please show your table definition

Comment: Yes, I know, I have created a table which is nested with struct and map.
I'm just wondering that is there a library that can do the insert from the java object.

Comment: Spark is the only one I can know of